# Converting images from a rectangle to a square (prefer PHP)

Tags: php

I've been running a site where users can upload and crop photos of themselves and the enforced image shape was a rectangle.

Lately, I've been developing the new version of the site, and the image shape I'm now using is square.

I might have around 30,000+ images, and I want to move them from the old site to the new, but I need to convert them from rectangles to squares:

[image]

Is there a way to to do this conversion without losing parts of the image (eg: without cutting off part of it) and without distorting the image eg: it becomes squished and doesn't look like it should?

The images are of people's faces.

Any advice on a conversion like this? I'm good with PHP, so maybe I can script a job to do the entire conversion. I just need to be able to convert one image successfully.

Comment: If it won't be "squished" and won't be cropped, the only solution is to leave empty space on either side. Are you okay with that?

Comment: possibly.. I did hear from someone that Facebook was able to do these kind of conversions... was just a comment... not sure if possible... it might have to be space either side or physical cropping...

Comment: No, either you have to sacrifice proportions or you sacrifice parts of the image. This is a logical problem, not a coding one.

You can have several versions of an image though, which is what Facebook does in some parts of their website.

Comment: Check this section you will find your awnser [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740929/php-how-do-i-convert-a-rectangle-image-to-a-square-image)